# how to write the algorithm in latex

Tags: algorithms

My code is below,  I didn't find the error.

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\textbf{Input} :$x_{k-1}$,$P_{k-1}$,$u_{k}$,$z_{k}$\;
\textbf{Output} : $x_{k}^{-}$,$P_{k}^{-}$ \\~\\
 $x_{k+1}={\Phi{x}}_{k-1}+{Bu}_{k}+{G\omega}_{k}$
 $P_{k}={\Phi{P}}_{k-1}{\Phi}^{T}+Q$
$K=PH^{T}(HPH^{T}+R)^{-1})$
 $z=(z_{k}-H_{k}x_{k})$
 $x_{k}^{-}=x_{k}+kz$
 $P_{k}^{-}=P-KHP$
\textbf{return}$ x_{k}^{-}$,$P_{k}^{-}$
 \caption{ \textsc{Kalman Filter} }
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you could complete your code snippet to a minimal working example: a short document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and contains as few lines of code/text as are necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: There are several LaTeX packages that are meant to assist with the typesetting of algorithms. Please tell us which package, or which packages, you employ.

Comment: %Algorithm
\usepackage[boxruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

Comment: Please do not create for each question a new unregistred account (and delete it after getting an answer). You are not able to comment and vote and accept doing that. Register one account and ask the staff to merge the other accounts for you! As far as I remember this is your third question about algorithmn ...

Comment: what can i do ?

Comment: but i have only this account

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `\;` to close every statement, otherwise content is consider part of the same line:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output\,}
\SetAlgoLined
\DontPrintSemicolon

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \Input{$x_{k - 1}$, $P_{k - 1}$, $u_k$, $z_k$}
  \Output{$x_{k}^{-}$, $P_k^{-}$}
  \BlankLine
  $x_{k + 1} = \Phi(x)_{k - 1} + Bu_k + G\omega_k$\;
  $P_k = \Phi(P)_{k - 1} \Phi^T + Q$\;
  $K = PH^T (HPH^T + R)^{-1})$\;
  $z = (z_k - H_k x_k)$\;
  $x_k^{-} = x_k + k z$\;
  $P_k^{-} = P - KHP$\;
  \textbf{return} $x_k^{-}$, $P_k^{-}$\;
  \caption{\textsc{Kalman Filter}}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: i want to put it in boxes

Comment: @houssem - Then just change `\usepackage{algorithm2e}` to `\usepackage[boxruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}`.

Comment: 186
LaTeX Error: Environment algorithm undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.186 \begin{algorithm}
                       [H]

Comment: @houssem: You should be more clear in your descriptions. [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) defines the `algorithm` environment. My guess is you're including something like `algpseudocode` or similar (from [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx)). Is that the case? Use your words to describe the problem...

Comment: how , I don't understand

Comment: @houssem: Nor do I. Here's a suggestion: Copy and paste your entire code, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, to [Pastebin](//pastebin.com) and then paste a link to that code here. Then we can try to figure things out.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/0gpREsf1

Comment: this is the formathttps://pastebin.com/5dS0Z40u

Comment: @houssem: Remove `\usepackage{algorithmicx}` as well as `\usepackage[english]{algorithm}` from your `format` file.

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: Environment algorithm undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.186 \begin{algorithm}
                       [H]
?

Comment: @houssem: You are loading [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e), which provides the `algorithm` environment. Did you remove the two other algorithm-type packages?

Comment: which one should be removed?

Comment: Like I said above, "Remove `\usepackage{algorithmicx}` as well as `\usepackage[english]{algorithm}` from your `format` file."

Comment: that's what I did but remains the same mistake

Comment: Perhaps the problem lies with `StyleThese.cls`. What does that look like?

Comment: like style report

Comment: @houssem: It's impossible to help you properly if you're not forthcoming with what's going on. Put yourself in my position with no frame of reference on your setup. Then spoon-feed me with enough information so I can replicate your issue. Here's a start: [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)

Comment: what can I do ??